# Naming convention for not-exported type names in Go

Tags: go, naming-conventions

I like to name my types using Pascal case - starting with an upper case letter. In Go this implies the name is exported.

To avoid export, I've started to prefix the type name with undercsore instead of lower-casing the first letter.

E.g: Instead of 
`type Column struct{}`, I use `type _Column struct{}` to avoid export.

I haven't seen this naming scheme used, but neither found any reason not to use it.

Since `golint` accepts it without complaint, I guess this is OK?

**Conclusion**: Based on answers and comments I've decided to stay with lower-cased type names.

Comment: The only definition of OK that matches here is *"goling accepts it without complaint"*. What about following the go usage instead of trying to reproduce what you did in another language ?

Comment: When in Rome do as the Romans do! Just use lower case names.

Comment: Why not just `column`? Since these names are unexported it doesn't really matter, but I don't think anyone would prefer `_Column` to `column`. To say nothing about autocompletion being easier when all unexported identifiers *don't* start with the same symbol.

Comment: No it is not OK as it is dead ugly, unnecessary and misleading.

Comment: I only partly agree on arguments about ugliness, autocompletion, reproduce from other languages etc, but I like and agree with the comment from Grzegors: When in Rome do as the Romans do! – since other arguments are just more or less weak opinions, including my own, I will follow this recommendation :)

Answer (score 5):

I'd suggest using `column` in preference to `_Column`, on the basis that the style used by the standard libraries follow that naming convention.

This is not explicit in the [Names section of the style guide](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#names), but based on the fact that underscores are generally discouraged, I'd say that using `_Column` is, at best, not idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

"I like to" and go don't super mix.

There are idiomatic bits and tooling enforced bits.

The community sticking to the standards makes for codebases that can be reasonably easy to read and comprehend by others.

I find this to be one of the best attributes of go.

Sure, channels and goroutines are nice.
Easily being able to read a codebase is often much more valuable.